# ProFTPd split logs to multiple files

Tags: ftp, logging, proftpd

Is there any way that I can split ProFTPd log file in to small files like Apache does?

```
proftpd.log (current)
proftpd.log.1 (archive)
proftpd.log.2 (archive)
proftpd.log.3 (archive)
etc ...
```

Currently proftpd.log has about 4GB and is difficult to browse.

I would be greatfull for any help.

Comment: In case you're running on a *nix platform, check out `logrotate`.